# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when ASP.NET client accesses the Service

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I'm trying to create an AJAX-Enabled WCF Service and an ASP.NET Client that Accesses the Service.

The error I get is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

at this line:

```
var service = new WcfService.Service1();
```

**This is my asp.net code :**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="GridView.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASPUserManager.Presentation.AspNetUI.GridView" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Users GridView</title>
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js"></script>
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/knockout.simpleGrid.3.0.js"></script>
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/clientServiceHelper.js"></script>--%>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
        <services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Service1.svc" />
        </services>
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>

 </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var service = new WcfService.Service1();
            service.GetAllUsers(onSuccess, null, null);

            function onSuccess(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
namespace WcfService
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        private ExceptionManager exManager;

        IApplicationService applicationService;

        public Service1()
        {
            this.applicationService = new ApplicationService();
        }

        #region Members

        public UsersDTO GetUser(UsersDTO userDTO)
        {
            return this.Process(() =>
            {
                return this.applicationService.GetUser(userDTO);
            });
        }

}
```

**IService1.cs**

```
namespace WcfService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "WcfService")]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        UsersDTO GetUser(UsersDTO userDTO);
    }
}
```

I hope I provided all necessary information to analyse this issue. If not please let me know. It would be great if someone could help me with this.
 I just can't see what could be the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery script before calling $(document).read

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            var service = new WcfService.Service1();
            //service.GetAllUsers(onSuccess, null, null);

            function onSuccess(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try to debug the javascript code, and see if the `var service = new WcfService.Service1()` line is hit.

Answer (score 0):

As Cristina Alboni suggested, I tried to debug the javascript code, and find out that I was trying to initialize the wcf in a wrong way, also i had to change some configuration in my web.config.